# How do i define partition columns to be part of the schema in an external table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an external table that I want to use to query hive partitioned data in GCS as described at [Querying externally partitioned data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-queries-gcs) .

My files (which are NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON) are stored in this structure:

gs://bucket/publish/dt=2022-01-13/hr=16/min=44

[image]

I am using terraform to define my external table and I have defined it like so:

```hcl
resource "google_bigquery_table" "external_table" {
  dataset_id          = var.dataset_id
  project             = var.project_id
  table_id            = var.table_id
  external_data_configuration {
    autodetect    = false
    source_uris   = ["gs://${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/publish/*"]
    source_format = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
    hive_partitioning_options {
      mode                     = "CUSTOM"
      source_uri_prefix        = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/publish/{dt:STRING}/{hr:STRING}/{min:STRING}"
      require_partition_filter = false
    }
  }
  schema = <<EOF
[
    {
        "name": "col1",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "col2",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "col3",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
EOF
}
```

It deploys OK however the partitioning columns don't show up in the schema of the table. If I try to issue

```sql
select dt,hr,min from mytable where dt = '...'
```

then I get an error:

> Error in query string: Error processing job 'XXX': Unrecognized name: dt

If I try and add those columns to the schema:

```hcl
resource "google_bigquery_table" "external_table" {
  dataset_id          = var.dataset_id
  project             = var.project_id
  table_id            = var.table_id
  external_data_configuration {
    autodetect    = false
    source_uris   = ["gs://${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/publish/*"]
    source_format = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
    hive_partitioning_options {
      mode                     = "CUSTOM"
      source_uri_prefix        = "gs://${google_storage_bucket.bucket.name}/publish/{dt:STRING}/{hr:STRING}/{min:STRING}"
      require_partition_filter = false
    }
  }
  schema = <<EOF
[
    {
        "name": "col1",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "col2",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "col3",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "dt",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "hr",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    },
    {
        "name": "min",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
    }
EOF
}
```

then I get an error when I try to query the table:

> Error while reading table: XXX, error message: Failed to add partition
> key dt (type: TYPE_STRING) to schema, because another column with the same name was already present.  This is not allowed. Full partition schema: [dt:TYPE_STRING, hr:TYPE_STRING, min:TYPE_STRING]

How can I configure my table so that the partition columns can be referred to in my SQL query?

Comment: TRY THIS QUERY ````select <cols except dt,hr,min> from mytable where dt = '...'````. I mean remove dt,hr,min for select, though it can be in where clause

Comment: thx for the suggestion but unfortunately this errors on the `dt` in the WHERE clause. Also, I would like these columns to be accessible in the SElECT clause

Comment: If that's the case then your file should have a copy of those columns with different name. Becoz hive does not stores col values on which you partition the data. But, for me strange thing is that u are unable to access them in WHERE.

Comment: The files do not have those columns in them but if I don’t define them in the schema then I can’t query against them (as explained in the question above)